# Using the Principle of Well Order, show that for all $n \in N$ it holds that $4^n -1$ is divisible by 3.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, well-orders, theorem-provers

Using the Principle of Well Order, show that for all $n \in N$ it holds that $4^n -1$ is divisible by 3.
I have already defined the set of counterexamples $C$, then I proved that for $n=1$ the proposition holds.
Then I established that $c$ (the minimum element of $C$) must be the successor of some natural number $k$ such that $c=k+1$ and therefore $k=c-1$, so that: $4^k -1$ is divisible by 3, apply the definition of divisibility to this last statement: $4^k -1=3m$, therefore, $4^{c-1} -1$ is divisible by 3.

Then, using the Division Algorithm, I can represent $4^c -1=3m+r$, from here I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Please state in English

Comment: Hi! I translate the post

Comment: `4^{c-1}-1` shows as $4^{c-1}-1$ as opposed to `4^c-1-1` which appears as $4^c-1-1$.  You surely mean the first here, not the second.

Comment: To continue, note that $4=3+1$ and so $4^c = 4\times 4^{c-1} = (3+1)\times 4^{c-1}$

Comment: For dozens of other ways to prove the statement, see [Alternative ways to prove that $4$ divides $5^n-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383531/alternate-ways-to-prove-that-4-divides-5n-1).  The proof you have started is essentially the same as the proofs by induction except for the way they are phrased.